# How to get ENV variables from Kubernetes Deployment to my server?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to do a rather simple thing, get my env variables to my application, but this doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect it to. I have a Golang server that's trying to connect to postgres DB

I am trying to connect as follows

```
func InitDb(ctx context.Context) (PgxIface, func() error, error) {
    dbUrl := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?sslmode=disable",
        os.Getenv("POSTGRES_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PORT"),
        os.Getenv("POSTGRES_DB"))

    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dbUrl)

    return conn, func() error { return conn.Close(ctx) }, nil
}
```

And my deployment.yaml file is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: example/auth 
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secret-config
                  key: password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: auth-db
            - name: POSTGRES_PORT
              value: '3306'
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              value: auth-db-srv
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
```

Docker file

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build

RUN apk add git

RUN mkdir /src
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN go build -o /tmp/auth ./main.go

FROM alpine:edge

COPY --from=build /tmp/auth /sbin/auth

CMD /sbin/auth
```

EDIT: Currently the env variables work (not sure what was happening before, might've been Skaffold issue as it started working after my PC was restarted...)

The password for some reason is `postgres\n` (with the \n)

```
[auth] postgres
[auth] postgres
[auth] 
[auth] auth-db-srv
[auth] 3306
[auth] auth-db
[auth] postgres://postgres:postgres
[auth] @auth-db-srv:3306/auth-db?sslmode=disable
[auth] Connecting to AMPQ server at amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/
[auth] Unable to connect to database: cannot parse `postgres://postgres:xxxxxx@auth-db-srv:3306/auth-db?sslmode=disable`: failed to parse as URL (parse "postgres://postgres:postgres\n@auth-db-srv:3306/auth-db?sslmode=disable": net/url: invalid control character in URL)
```

All of the env variables do work except the secret

`postgre-config.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-secret-config
type: Opaque
data:
  password: somepassword
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `printenv` inside the container do the variables show up? The config seems valid, are you sure you don't overwrite them yourself?

Comment: I was fiddling with it and it seems to have started to work more expectedly, not sure if I had a typo or something before. Currently only the password isn't being loaded properly it seems, (it's loaded as postgres\n for some reason). Added an edit